# Entire functions $f$ for which there exists a positive constant $M$ such that $|f(z)|\le M|\cos z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Find all entire functions $f$ for which there exists a positive constant $M$ such that $|f(z)|\le M|\cos z|$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

I think to prove this, we need to use the Identity theorem, i.e. analytic functions are determined by their values in a convergent sequence. In this case, we can find real sequence converging to $\pi/2$. In that case, given any $\epsilon >0$, eventually $|f(z_n)|$ must be less than $M\epsilon$. But this does not guarantee that $f(z_n)=0$, which is what I need to prove that $f\equiv 0$. How can I sharpen this proof? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that $f(z)=\cos z$ is itself such a function, so you won't be able to show that $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Micah But $M$ could be less than $1$.

Comment: Look at the meromorphic function $f(z)/cos(z)$

Comment: @Blake $f(z)/\cos(z)$ is not entire at the zeros of $\cos$ though.

Comment: @takecare: It could be, but it doesn't have to be (unless there's some part of the problem statement you didn't copy). Even if it is, $f(z)=M \cos z$ is another such function...

Comment: What does Riemann's removable singularity theorem tell you?

Comment: @Blake That theorem has not yet appeared for this exercise. Is that the only way to go through this problem?

Comment: It might have not appeared in the generality that you see on Wikipedia, but I would think there would be something to the effect of "bounded near singularity implies removable singularity" in your text. Which are you using?

Comment: @Blake Complex variables with applications by Ponnusamy and Silverman. Singularity appears in the next chapter alongside Riemann's theorem. I think the authors mistakenly put this exercise here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong theorem ,use Liouville's Theorem -|f(z)/cos(z)| <= M                      (note the singularities when cos(z) =0 are removable so the quotient is a bounded entire function haence must be constant which gives F(z)=A cos(z) with A a fixed complex number