# Finding all entire functions $f(z)$ for which $|f(z)|\leq M.|\sin z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I've seen the other way for this question ([Entire functions $f$ for which there exists a positive constant $M$ such that $|f(z)|\le M|\cos z|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278494/entire-functions-f-for-which-there-exists-a-positive-constant-m-such-that)), I just want to make sure that the same argument can be applied for the following question.

> Find all entire functions $f(z)$ for which there exists a positive constant $M$ such that 
>   $$|f(z)|\geq M.|\sin z|\:\:\text{for all}\:\:z\in\mathbb{C}.$$

From the above assuption, I can say the zeros of $f(z)$ is a subset of zeros of $\sin z $. Define $g(z)=\frac{\sin z}{f(z)}$. Hence $|g(z)|\leq M$, so the isoalted singularities of $g(z)$, becomes removable and so $g(z)$ can be extended to an entire function which by Liouville's theorem it becomes constant.

Thus $$f(z)= k \sin z,\:\:\text{ for some nonzero constant }k.$$

Comment: @zhw That's the questsion and No! that's right!

Comment: "I can say the zeros of $\sin z$ is a subset of zeros of $f(z). $ " No, it's the other way around

Comment: @zhw. Thanx! edited.